# Viewport isn't detected correctly on iPad mini

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to adjust styling of my site depending on different devices.
I'm getting wrong result for iPad mini.

I'm using this meta tag in the head of html: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

and the styling is triggered by javascript:

```
} else if (('{{ location }}' == '/security' && $(window).width() > 414) && ('{{ location }}' == '/security' && $(window).width() <= 768)) {

...
...
}
```

This is triggered just fine on Androids with the css viewport of 768 but iPad mini allegedly has the same viewport but it won't trigger this condition.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What does it report when you log `$(window).width()`?

Comment: it gives me 768

Comment: Then it should work … if `'{{ location }}'` is `/security` and a typo somewhere hasn't make it `/security/` or similar

Comment: I just find out it's 1024 and not 768. Wrong js block was being executed. After the right one was ran it showed me 1024. Mystery solved.